What is the best way to get a tighter seal for garage door?
I would like to use the Green Hinge System but I have a Wayne Dalton door and the Green Hinge System isn't compatible. The wheels in the track are pretty loose. The door forms a good seal against the weatherstripping but when the lawn blower hits the door, it pushes the door away from the weatherstripping and blows in dirt and debris.
Another alternative for the Green Hinge System?
I checked into Thermotrak but they appear out of business. Nobody answers the phone there or responds to email.

What does pretty loose mean?  Maybe new wheels if they are worn?

Garage doors are not watertight and certainly not air tight. Attempting to make them that way quickly becomes an exercise in futility.  Just quit blowing the lawn blower toward the door.

If I wanted a weather-tight garage door, my first step would be to replace the lift door with swinging doors. Then weatherstrip the hell out of them.
